# WebForms Request timed out after Application Pool Recycle

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, iis-8

After each of the past two IIS application pool recycle events, my WebForms application began experiencing a large volume of Request timed out errors. Application is running on IIS 8 and targets .NET Framework 4.5.1.
Users were able to load the login page with no problem, but prior to or during the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage call, the process would hang and eventually the execution timeout would be reached. Judging from my logs, this happened to every user. Redirecting some traffic away from the app running on one application pool to an alternative version running in another application pool or service allowed users to log in from the alternate application with no issue. Once enough traffic redirected away from the app with requests timing out, that app would eventually allow users to login again without timeout.
This happened within a couple of minutes of the last two application pool recycles and has not happened previously. Our logs do not show any database connection errors or timeouts during these periods. No configuration changes have been made immediately prior to the start of this error (or in quite some time, for that matter).
Any ideas how the login page would load without issue but could not redirect to the authenticated portion of the application?

Comment: The symptoms indicate possible flaws in the login page. Hang dump analysis would be the quickest, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com if you find the steps too difficult to follow.

Comment: @LexLi - By way of clarity, the login page is fully accessible and loads instantly so the IIS process does not appear to have stopped responding. Additionally, no code on the login page or any of the underlying methods used within that page have changed anytime recently. Login works fine once traffic is diverted to an alternate version of the application running on the same server but different app pool. Do you still think a hang dump analysis is appropriate here?